# How to sort result from one SQL query with data from other table

Tags: sql, join, sql-order-by

I have a database with two tables. In one table I have the information of costumers with a column 
`costumer_id` and a column `costumer_name` and I have a table with customer orders with columns `order_id` and `customer_id`. The tables look like this:

Customers:

```
+-------------+---------------+
| customer_id | customer_name |
+-------------+---------------+
|           1 | Joe           |
|           2 | Michael       |
|           3 | Ben           |
+-------------+---------------+
```

Orders:

```
+----------+-------------+
| order_id | customer_id |
+----------+-------------+
|        1 |           1 |
|        2 |           2 |
|        3 |           3 |
+----------+-------------+
```

I now have the following query, which gives me the amount of orders from each costumer. The results are ordered by customer_id.

```
SELECT customer_id, COUNT(order_id) 
FROM Orders 
GROUP BY customer_id 
ORDER BY customer_id ASC;
```

Now I want the result to be ordered by the customer_name from the Customer table with a query. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What database do you use ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have it with the ID:

```
SELECT c.customer_name name
       , COUNT(order_id) sumarum
       , o.customer_id id
FROM Orders O
left join Customers C
on o.customer_id = c.customer_id
GROUP BY customer_name, o.customer_id
ORDER BY c.customer_name, o.customer_id;
```

Or without the ID (Just name and count):

```
select name
       , sumarum
from (SELECT o.customer_id id
       , COUNT(order_id) sumarum
       , c.customer_name name
FROM Orders O
left join Customers C
on o.customer_id = c.customer_id
GROUP BY customer_name, o.customer_id
ORDER BY c.customer_name, o.customer_id);
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7ece534912c33f7c181af26bb290aa7e)